# finish() is closing two activities instead one

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

I've made an app that does the following:

activity A --> activity B --> activity C

activity A --> activity B2 --> activity C

When you close B, B2 or C, it goes to the previous activity. If you close A, it exits from the app.

If you arrive to C from B, C works in one way, but if you arrive from B2, C works in a bit different way.

This works perfectly in emulator and all devices that I could check, but a problem has appeared in two Xperia (models ARC & U) with android 4.0.4.

The problem appers when they arrive to C from B. When they close C they go back to A instead to B. If they arrive to C from B2, when they close go back to B2.

I can't understand that. It's supposed that C had to work in the same way in both cases.

And the other question is: How is possible that the app works perfectly in all devices except this two?

Any idea? How can I solve this problem?

Editing to add code:

Opening C from B:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (position+1) {
    case 1:
        if(random == true){
            AnimalsBD.cmpt = Integer.parseInt(ABD.getNAct(Integer.toString(Aguila.ordre)))+1;
            }
        Intent a = new Intent ("com.android.JIA.Animals.1");
        startActivity(a);
    break;
    case 2:
        if(random == true){
            AnimalsBD.cmpt = Integer.parseInt(ABD.getNAct(Integer.toString(Anec.ordre)))+1;
            }
        Intent b = new Intent ("com.android.JIA.Animals.2");
        startActivity(b);
    break;
```

Opening C from B2:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {     
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    mpCorrecte = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correcte);
    mpIncorrecte = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.incorrecte);

    if(start){
    switch (position+1) {
    case 1:
        if(numSo==1){
            start = false;
            mpCorrecte.start();
            mpCorrecte.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Intent a = new Intent ("com.android.JIA.Animals.1");
                    startActivity(a);}                  
            });
        }else{
            mpIncorrecte.start();
        }
    break;
    case 2:
        if(numSo==2){
            start = false;
            mpCorrecte.start();
            mpCorrecte.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    Intent a = new Intent ("com.android.JIA.Animals.2");
                    startActivity(a);}                  
            });
        }else{
            mpIncorrecte.start();
        }
    break;
```

In both cases I'm opening a final activity from a gridview. All the final activities works equally.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code how you calling different activities

Comment: I've edited the entry with my code.

Comment: Can you provide exact Android software version for the devices you tested on? I can try running a similar example on those devices.

Comment: The android version is 4.0.4 in both devices, but don't worry, the problem in solved. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've could solve the problem.

There was a finish() lost in the OnDestroy() method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    ABD.erase();
            finish();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Now the question is: why this finish() didn't do anything in any device except in these two models?

Unsolved mistery...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to open new activity.

```
        Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
            OpeningActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Replace `CurrentActivity` and `OpeningActivity`

**How is possible that the app works perfectly in all devices except this two?**
You have to check it manually by selecting different types phones like different platform , different screen size and different specification .

Comment: I've checked with my friends and the problem still exists in these Sony Xperia.

Comment: **You have to check it manually by selecting different types phones**... It is possible to emulate a specific device with a specific android version? I mean, can I emulate a Sony Xperia Arc with android 4.0.4 for example?

Comment: @Nirali any idea about a possible solution?

Comment: Emulator has its own disadvantages

Comment: Yes, I've changed it, but the problem still exist. Same problem with the same devices.
Any suggestion?